# How to integrate $\int(x\pi-x^2)\cos(kx)dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

My question is can I solve by integrating by parts if I do $u = (x\pi-x^2)$,or first I have to do $∫[x\pi \cos(kx)-x^2\cos(kx)]dx$ and then split it in two integrals $\int x\pi\cos(kx)dx-\int x^2\cos(kx)dx$ ?

Comment: Why not try both and see which works, and perhaps learn when "parts" does and doesn't work?

Comment: They will wind up being about the same amount of work.

Comment: You can integrate without splitting as well. Just choose the polynomial as the first function and cosine as the second. You would need to apply integration by parts, twice though.

Comment: @vnd yes,that's exactly what i did and i obtained an answer,but i think that  the answer would be different if i split in two integrals.And longer also

Comment: @user277620, in that case, you should check by splitting as well. You would get the same terms, though ! but one should convince themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may **directly** integrate by parts twice,
$$
\int(\pi x-x^2) \cos (kx)\:dx=\frac1k(\pi x-x^2)\sin (k x)-\frac1k\int(\pi-2x) \sin (kx)\:dx
$$ then
$$
\begin{align}
&\int(\pi x-x^2) \cos (kx)\:dx\\&=\frac1k(\pi x-x^2)\sin (k x)-\frac1k\left((\pi-2x)(-\frac1k \cos (kx))+\int(-2) \frac1k \cos (kx)\:dx\right)
\end{align}
$$ getting

> $$
> \int(\pi x-x^2) \cos (kx)\:dx=\frac1{k^3}\left(2+k^2\pi  x-k^2x^2\right) \sin (kx)+\frac1{k^2}(\pi -2 x) \cos (kx)+ C
> $$

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Another way:}$
$$
\pi\frac{d}{dk}\int \sin k x dx + \frac{d^2}{dk^2}\int \cos k x dx = \int \left(\pi x-x^2\right)\cos kx dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that does not use integration by parts.  We observe that

$$\frac{d^2}{dk^2}\int \cos (kx)\,dx=-\int x^2\cos (kx)\,dx$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dk}\int \sin (kx)\,dx=\int x\cos (kx)\,dx$$

Therefore,

$$\int x^2\cos (kx)\,dx=-\frac{d^2}{dk^2}\left(\frac{\sin kx}{k}\right)=\frac{x^2\sin kx}{k}+\frac{2x\cos kx}{k^2}-\frac{2\sin kx}{k^3}$$

and

$$\int x\cos (kx)\,dx=-\frac{d}{dk}\left(\frac{\cos kx}{k}\right)=\frac{x\sin kx}{k}+\frac{x\sin kx}{k^2}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful to warrant an up vote, I am happy to delete.